# Let $f$ be a relation from $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ given by $f([x])=[x^2+6x]$. Prove or disprove that this is a well-defined function

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Let $f$ be a relation from $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ given by $f([x])=[x^2+6x]$. Prove or disprove that this is a well-defined function.

---

I've attempted to both prove it and find a counterexample, but I've reached a dead-end in either case.

For the proof, this is what I have so far.

Let $[a]=[b]$, then $4k=a-b$, for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
Now suppose that 
\begin{align*}
(a^2+6a)-(b^2+6b)&=(a-b)(b+a)+6(a-b)\\
=&4k(b+a)+6(4k)\\
=&4k[b+a+6]\\
=& ?
\end{align*}

From here I'm not sure where to go, if we can in fact prove it.

Can anyone give a push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just note that $a-b=4k=2\cdot (2k)$ and so $a$ and $b$ are both odd or both even. Then $a+b$ is even and you can write $4k[b+a+6]=4k[2k'+2\cdot 3]=8[k(k'+3)].$

Comment: "Then a+b is odd..." Do you mean even here? Hence, $a+b=2k'$?

Comment: @B.V. : yes I am sorry I regularly swap them in english... Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome.